# Linker error using boost::log in a static lib

Tags: c++, logging, boost, linker

I have a static lib which uses Boost.Log. When I want to test some functions of this lib in a seaparate test project, I get the follwing linker errors:

```
undefined reference to `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::aux::global_storage::get_or_init(boost::typeindex::stl_type_index, boost::shared_ptr<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::aux::logger_holder_base> (*)())'

undefined reference to `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::aux::throw_odr_violation(boost::typeindex::stl_type_index, boost::typeindex::stl_type_index, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sources::aux::logger_holder_base const&)'

undefined reference to `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::code_convert_impl(wchar_t const*, unsigned long, std::string&, std::locale const&)'
```

I have a logger-class in the static lib which configures Boost.Log and installs a global logger. I don't really know what I have to link against the test project to get it linked successfully. Maybe you have an idea?

With CMake I added the following libs to the static lib:

```
target_link_libraries(RBSLib
        boost_system
        boost_filesystem
        boost_python
        boost_date_time
        boost_program_options
        boost_log
        boost_thread        
        pq
        ssl
        crypto
        boost_regex
        pthread
        dl
)
```

And the follwing libs to my test project:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
        boost_system
        boost_date_time
        boost_unit_test_framework
        tbb
        pq
        ssl
        pthread
${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/../rbs/libRBSLib.a
        boost_thread
        boost_filesystem
        boost_program_options
        crypto
        boost_log
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your new library dependencies and also the same things when you did while compiling your static lib. In another words you need to add the include path and libs of boost(which is needed to compile your lib) to the test project's compiler and linker properties. This is because your new lib isn't statically linked together with boost(or any other library). It still needs that external libs explicitly.

Comment: I think I did it like you've explained. I have updated my post with some CMake-parts, maybe there is an error in the order of the libs? The errors changed, when I move the libRBSLib.a entry down.

Comment: @Paul i don't think it's the order of the libs. Your test project's dependencies should involve the static lib's dependencies. Either delete unnecessary libs in the static lib's config or add them to the test project (boost_python for example).

Comment: Okay, I haven't added the boost lib directory to the Cmake-file of my test project. Now it compiles :-)